# ～としたら What is the purpose in this context?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I found the following sentence

> たとえばさえりさんの頭が10ヶ月ずっと痛かった**としたら**、それが通常になると思いますか？

From this article: http://liginc.co.jp/241030

Why does he opt to use ずっと痛かったとしたら rather than simply ずっと痛かったら ?

What is the nuance being communicated in cases like these?

Answer (score 4):

The difference is fairly subtle, but it is there.

The nuance is that using 「としたら」 helps the speaker emphasize the fact that it is a ***hypothetical*** discussion that he is engaged in at the moment.

I must add, though, that the difference that 「としたら」 creates is **not** all that substantial because 「ずっと[痛]{いた}かったら」 is already hypothetical without using 「としたら」.

I think that the difference is like one between:

> "If the pain were to continue" and "If the pain continued".

The former would have the feeling of 「～～としたら」.